# How can I include a field that is not part of the group clause in a ActiveRecord query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

(Ruby 1.9.3-p429; Rails 3.0.6)
Recent changes to the way we queue our tests have rendered our last_ids scope:

```
last_ids = tests.where('end_time != 0').
                 group(:condition1, :condition2, :condition3, :condition4).
                 select('max(id) as id')
```

logically obsolete. Previously, the tests were queued and completed in the same order as the test record was created so the maximum id for each grouping was also the latest test record. Now, for efficiency, we have a queuing algorithm that no longer guarantees the order of the tests. I have added an "end_time" column to the test table. My solution, so far is too slow to use:

```
max_end_times = tests.where('end_time != 0').
                        group(:condition1, :condition2, :condition3, :condition4).
                        .maximum(:end_time)
```

which yields a hash: {[:condition0, :condition1, :condition2, :condition3]=>:endtime}. then I do as follows:

```
hash.each_pair do |key, value|
  last_ids << tests.select(:id).
                      where(condition0: [key[0]]).
                      where(condition1: [key[1]]).
                      where(condition2: [key[2]]).
                      where(condition3: [key[3]]).
                      where(end_time: [value]).
                      map(&:id)[0]
end
```

This works, but it is entirely too slow.

So...does anyone know how to match the maxumum(:end_time) for a given grouping but only return the :id's? (all i need to get from the database is the :ids of the lastest test for each grouping).

EDIT: clarification.

Comment: So all you want are the ids of the latest test in each group of 4 conditions? Do you need to match them up with the groups? Also, using `end_time` may be unreliable if the column doesn't have enough precision, and the problem will get worse as computers get faster. It may appear that multiple tests finish at exactly the same time - does it matter which id you want in the case of a tie?

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord::Calculations#pluck`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck

Edit: If you don't have `#pluck`, you could still probably do this in one query & a `#map` with:

```
tests.where('end_time != 0').
             group(:condition1, :condition2, :condition3, :condition4).
             select('id, max(created_at)').map(&:id)
```

Comment: I saw pluck...Unfortunately, I am stuck back on rails 3.0.6.

Comment: That stinks. I just saw that there's an `#ids` method now, too, but I think that's new in 4.0.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm not sure that pluck or its predecessors will do the trick. By the time I get past group and maximum, id could be lost. hmmm...

Comment: RE: edit
(id, max(end_time))?  This the really strange thing. I've tried this and the result is:
{[21, "UNIT4", "3930et", "tengig"]=>2013-07-31 05:53:21 -0700, [2, "", "3940", "multi"]=>2013-08-04 21:56:19 -0700} (among others).

no id's to be found. This is proving to be pretty tricky.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I guess I'm not trying to output that hash -- you probably want where instead of group? I'm honestly not sure what those conditions are supposed to be doing in your data model.

Comment: I'm not trying to output that hash either. All I want is the ids of the records that, when grouped by the four conditions (which are table columns) have the most recent end_time. I am sorry if my explanation is wonky. I do appreciate the help, though. I have been through all of my coworkers and haven't come up with a solution.

Comment: (I have also, until just recently, only lurked around StackOverflow. If my etiquette if off, I apologize).

Comment: No, you've not been impolite, I've just been confused about what you're trying to get. Let me try again.

Comment: So when I try the .group(:condition1, :condition2).select('id, max(created_at)') on a model in my app, it gives me what I'd expect -- an array of record objects with ids.

Comment: hmmm...I must have something hindering the output. Could be a special case that I haven't accounted for.  Thanks again for your time.